# What are the options to get \mathcal working for lower case letters?

Tags: latex, fonts

that is I'd like `$\mathcal{l}=\mathcal{L}$` to produce two letters. I know `\mathcal{}` works (predictably) on upper case letters only. Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try the following (in your preamble):

```
\DeclareFontFamily{OT1}{pzc}{}
\DeclareFontShape{OT1}{pzc}{m}{it}{<-> s * [1.10] pzcmi7t}{}
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathpzc}{OT1}{pzc}{m}{it}
```

Then `$\mathpzc{l}=\mathcal{L}$` should work. Note that `$\mathpzc{L}$` is not the same as `$\mathcal{L}$`.

The scaling is designed to make the `\mathpzc` font about the same size as the `\mathcal` font.

This is using Zapf Chancery which is the standard PostScript calligraphic font.